# Explain Resources Monitor memory information?

Tags: resource-monitor

I know that this question is too old but i can't find answer anywhere so I wanna to explian to me what is information meaning

[image]

I know only the mean of "Installed" and "Total"

Total means full size of memory in my machine

Installed means full size that computer can see , read and use it

so i want to know what is mean of Hardware Reserved / In Use / Modified / Standby /Free /Available /  Cached

because i use this program to run program like virtual machine or render program so i specif how many size of ram can those programs take it from Resource monitor

and sorry for my bad language in English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **I want to know what is [the meaning] of "Hardware Reserved", "In Use", "Modified", "Standby", "Free", "Available" [and] "Cached"**

[The usable memory may be less than the installed memory on Windows 7-based computers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610)

```
Memory allocation   Description
-----------------   -----------------------------------------------------------
Hardware Reserved   Memory that is reserved for use by the BIOS and some 
                    drivers for other peripherals

In Use              Memory that is used by process, drivers, or the operating 
                    system

Modified            Memory whose contents must go to disk before it can be used 
                    for another purpose

Standby             Memory that contains cached data and code that is not 
                    actively in use

Free                Memory that does not contain any valuable data and that 
                    will be used first when processes, drivers, or the  
                    operating system need more memory
```

…

```
Available           Amount of memory (including standby and free memory) that 
                    is immediately available for use by processes, drivers, 
                    and the operating system

Cached              Amount of memory (including standby and modified memory) 
                    that contains cached data and code for rapid access by 
                    processes, drivers, and the operating system

Total               Amount of physical memory that is available to the 
                    operating system, device drivers, and processes

Installed           Amount of physical memory installed in the computer
```